# Is it okay to use compositor after rendering animation's image sequence?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Is it okay to use compositor after rendering animation's image sequence? Will there be any issue or downside to it? Or is it just the same when you do it during render?

Comment: i think it might be even better because you can try different settings quicker if you are not satisfied with the result because you already have the "raw" render result.

Comment: But if you haven't already, definitely choose OpenEXR as file format, not the default PNG. Because PNG cannot preserve the complete dynamic range of colors and lights since all RGB values are limited to the 0 to 1 range - which doesn't produce good results if you want to, for example, create glow on bright spots with a _Glare_ node. And if you set the OpenEXR codec to DWAA, there is no noticeable loss in quality and the files are even smaller than PNGs.